# store image to SD card

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-sdcard, android-image

i'm using cropping functionality in my android application and it works fine but i want to save cropped image to my `SD Card`. For that what steps needs to be followed?

Comment: have a try with below link http://www.androidworks.com/crop_large_photos_with_android

Comment: Please follow the below tutorial . this is what you want. [**Capture and Crop an Image with the Device Camera**](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera/) You can send the browsed image also for cropping via intent
. You are having better example in this [tutorial](http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-select-and-crop-image-on-android/) also.

Comment: i hv tried this links and it crops images bt dont store image to SD Card..

Comment: Just you have to get the bitmap or URI from those tutorials and have to save in your preferred location .. that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `Bitmap` you cropped is called `yourBitmap`

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File f = new File (sdcard, "filename.png");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
yourBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out)
```

Comment: this code will create a png file. pathToStore have to point to the sdcard

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
{
    String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
                                "/NewFolder";
        File dir = new File(file_path);
        if(!dir.exists)
           dir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(dir, "myImage.png");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
}
```

Following permission is required in `Manifest` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: @MonalGodiwala what was that? is my solution wrong or not working now?

Comment: @MonalGodiwala you accept that first and then reject so I guess is there any issue in this code.

Answer (score 1):

first for get image store in sdcard:-

```
public static String storeImage(Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {

        String stored = null;

        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(sdcard, filename + ".png");

        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            stored = "success";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stored;
    }
```

second get image from sdcard:-

```
public static File getImage(String imagename) {

        File mediaImage = null;
        try {
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir = new File(root);
            if (!myDir.exists())
                return null;

            mediaImage = new File(myDir.getPath() + imagename);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mediaImage;
    }
```

**3 Convert image from sdcard to bitmap**

```
File file = CommonUtils.getImage("/CoverPic.png");

                String path = file.getAbsolutePath();

                if (path != null)
                    picture = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
```